# Array code Compile error[c]

Tags: c, arrays

Can anyone tell me whats the problem with this code and how Can I fix it? (Compile error) thank you! :)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int[] initArray(int arr[]);
void printArray(int arr[]);

 int main()
 {
      int myGrades[2];
      myGrades = initArray(myGrades);
      printArray(myGrades);
      return (0);
 }

 int[] initArray(int arr[])
 {
      arr[0] = 78;
      arr[1] = 86;
      return arr; 
 }

 void printArray(int arr[])
 {
     printf("My grade in English is: %d!\n",arr[0]);
     printf("My grade in History is %d! What an achievement!\n",arr[1]);
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure you need this to write `int[] initArray(int arr[]`?

Comment: No,but still have the problem.

Comment: @NoNameP [Try this](http://ideone.com/fZqfSN)

Comment: it's long time i didn't had any thing to do with C++. but i remember once i wanted to use it in VS, and some specific project type, i had to use the "using std" or something similar import, and it had it's own order ...here found it: `using namespace std` i'm not sure what kind of error you receive that i be able to help you, but take a look at this one

Comment: @deadManN What has [tag:c++] to do with this?

Comment: @deadManN The question was tagged `C` and not `C++`

Comment: @deadManN: that's terrible advice even if the question was about C++. If that's all you remember, better forget that too.

Comment: Is there another way without using Pointers?  never knew Pointers and I do not understand it

Comment: If you don't understand pointers or you never learned them, Why do you still learn the Language ?

Comment: [Try This](http://ideone.com/NWgUkB) and  also [This](http://ideone.com/1zKM6U) and read iharob Answer

Comment: @Mat :D sorry then, cause i didn't see any thing wrong with his program, (the way i remember it), again sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You cannot assign to *arrays* in [c](/questions/tagged/c), so this

   ```
   int myGrades[2];
   myGrades = initArray(myGrades);
   ```

   is invalid, you simply cannot assign to an array but passing the array as a parameter should modify it inside the function as a pointer to the first element of the array is really passed, see the next point to understand why.

   To fix this part, just remove the assignment

   ```
   initArray(myGrades);
   ```

   is enough.
2. You cannot define a function like this

   ```
   int[] initArray(int arr[])
   {
        arr[0] = 78;
        arr[1] = 86;
        return arr; 
   }
   ```

Quoting [this document, the C11 Standard Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

> **6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes)**
>
> 1. A function declarator shall not specify a return type that is a function type or an array
>      type.

The `[]` syntax cannot be used for a function return type, also as a function parameter it will become a `int` poitner anyway so using `int arr[]` can be misleading, for example you can try to apply the `sizeof` operator to it, and it will give you the size of a pointer.

Change it to

```
    void initArray(int *arr)
    {
         arr[0] = 78;
         arr[1] = 86;
    }
```

and it should compile.

Although, the returned pointer is only valid in the scope where you defined `arr`, in your program it's valid in `main()` so pretty much everywhere if you pass `arr` as a parameter to any function it will be fine. The point is that you don't need to return it at all since the original array (*the one you passed to the function*) is altered in place.

Comment: By making that change will make `myGrades = initArray(myGrades);` to be `incompatible types when assigning to type ‘int[2]’ from type ‘int *’|`

Comment: @Michi it's invalid already.

Comment: I know and i didn't down voted you by the way :D

Comment: But now I understand why the downvote, I completely missed that!

Comment: Is there another way without using Pointers? never knew Pointers and I do not understand it

Comment: You can't because once you pass the array as a parameter it's already a pointer. You don't have to deal with it and that means that you should not care if it's a pointer. BUT YOU CAN NEVER ASSIGN TO AN ARRAY.

Comment: There is no need for `int *initArray(int *arr)` in his program `void initArray(int *arr)` and removing the return statement will be enough.

Comment: @NoNameP If you really need to avoid Pointer notation (instead of `*arr` just use `arr[]`), then you [need something like this](http://ideone.com/D6OKCG). But you should know, that `arr[]` used as function argument is a pointer.

Comment: @Michi Im trying the code but I have a Compile error in the last line("sytax error at end of input") What I need to do to fix it?

Comment: Copy and paste the whole code.

Comment: I did it  but still have

Comment: Thank you very much @iharob